# Whats the best way to unit test a function that calls a UDP server

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have been asked to write some unit tests for some code written in Java.

I'm testing using JUnit.

I have a function that calls a UDPS and returns something like the ID, I gave in the call and the time.

Is there a way I can test this without calling the server or am I best off calling it and testing the response?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Without some code sample to see how it is made it is hard to know for sure, but have you tried using a mock for the part that does the call. I assume that there is a service that handles the TCP communication. If you can mock that service you can make it return what you want and so you isolate your implementation.

Comment: Read about Mockito.

Comment: The solution is dependency injection and mocking. Read up on those two concepts and come back if you have problems understanding them.